# Excel Macro, insert each row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble reforming the order excel from our ecommerce store to a format that our finance software can read.
I've included two pictures underneath. The first one shows the export from our store orders. And the second one shows the result we need for our finance software. The Macro should add a new row underneath each existing row. In that new row it should

- In column B always fill the number 499027
- In column H take the amount from the row above and make it negative
- In column K copy the same value from the row above

This process should be repeated for every existing row. I've already spent hours trying to adjust existing macro's but I've only managed to add blank new rows ... If someone could help me out this would be awesome.

[image: This image gives an example of how the export from our ecommerce store looks]

[image: This is the format I need to be able to upload the orders in our finance software]

Comment: Can you post your existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a simple loop that will read your worksheet from the bottom row to the 2nd row.

In each iteration, insert a new row and write to that new row.

If you have a large data set, you might want to place your worksheet in an array first, make changes in your array, and then rewrite to the worksheet.

But this should do what you need...

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim r As Long

    With ws
        For r = lastRow(ws) To 2 Step -1
            .Rows(r + 1).Insert
            .Cells(r + 1, 2) = 499027
            .Cells(r + 1, 8) = .Cells(r, 8) * -1
            .Cells(r + 1, 12) = .Cells(r, 12)
        Next
    End With

End Sub

Function lastRow(ws As Worksheet, Optional col As Variant = 1) As Long
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

> [image]

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you so much for helping me out here! :-)